# Java Opencv DNN get(i, 2)[0]

Tags: java, opencv

I've been trying various ways to extract the confidence value from the detections.
I either get this: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot load from double array because the return value of "org.opencv.core.Mat.get(int, int)" is null

If I use this:

```
                double confidence;
                confidence = detections.get(i, 2)[0];
```

or if I change my code below get a null value!

```
                double[] detection;
                detection = detections.get(i, 2);
                //System.out.println("c : "+confidence);
                
                if (detection != null) {
                    confidence = detection[0];
                    System.out.println("i : " + i + " Confidence : " + confidence);
                }
```

If I dump detections I get:

```
dump : [1.6463306;
 0.39511931;
 0.59267896;
 1.778037;
 0.52682579;
 0.46097255;
 1.8438902;
etc...
```

I need someone to point out where I'm going wrong, as I can't figure it out!

https://forum.opencv.org/t/cant-get-a-confidence-value-from/12151

Answer (score 0):

I fixed that section of my code with a previous example on the old forum:

I will make another post in a few days if i can't figure why I'm going wrong with the next step.

https://answers.opencv.org/question/224079/java-dnn-help/

```
            float[] data = new float[7];
            
            for (int i = 0; i < detections.rows(); i++) {
                detections.get(i, 0, data);
                double confidence = data[2];
               
                if (confidence > CONFIDENCE_THRESHOLD){
                    //frame.width //frame.height //frame.cols //frame.rows
                    int x1 = (int)(data[3] * frame.cols());
                    int y1 = (int)(data[4] * frame.rows());
                    int x2 = (int)(data[5] * frame.cols());
                    int y2 = (int)(data[6] * frame.rows());
                    bboxes.add(new Rect(x1, y1, x2 - x1, y2 - y1));
                    Imgproc.rectangle(frameFace, new org.opencv.core.Point(x1, y1), new org.opencv.core.Point(x2, y2), new org.opencv.core.Scalar(0, 255, 0), (int) Math.round(frame.rows() / 150), 8, 0);                   
                }
```